# Python: counting frequency for two columns with the same possible values

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, frequency

I have two columns with *two possible values (0 or 1)*. One column is the *predicted value* and the other is the *real value*. Something like this.

```
ID Predicted Real  
1   1        1  
2   1        0  
3   0        0  
4   0        1  
5   1        0  
6   1        0
```

I want to count the frequency *for 0 and 1 on each column*. Something like this

```
Value Predicted Real  
1      4         2  
0      2         4
```

And I *want to make a vertical bar plot with the results*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply `pd.value_counts` to the dataframe (assuming ID is the index and not a column, if not set ID as index first)

```
out = df.apply(pd.value_counts).rename_axis('Value').reset_index()
```

---

```
   Value  Predicted  Real
0      0          2     4
1      1          4     2
```

---

```
df.apply(pd.value_counts).rename_axis('Value').plot(kind='bar') #customize as you want
```

[image]

Comment: a last question...how can I add the value on the top of every column in the plot?

Comment: @YurguenPeñarandaThomas I am not very well with plots, since this is majorly a pandas question , I would suggest you open a seperate question for plotting using python. :)